# Wnen the synchronized or volatile keywords are used which variables are synced with main memory

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

If a variable is declared as volatile then for every read access the local cache is updated from main memory and for every write access the local cache is flushed to main memory. But which variables are synched? I believe that if I declare v to be volatile that is not the only variable that is synched. But some other(or all) variables in the thread cache is also synched. A thread stack consists of several frames each for every method called. Does it go ahead and sync every frame? Does a synchronized block sync every variable in the object?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clarify what you mean be a "cache flush".  accessing volatile variables *does* have memory effects outside of the variable itself.  in fact, volatile variables have the same memory semantics as a synchronized block.  everything done by a thread before it writes a volatile variable is flushed to "main memory" in such a way that any other thread which subsequently reads that volatile variable will see the effects.  that said, the guarantees of volatile variables are scoped such that the only guarantees are related to accesses on the *same* volatile variable.  i.e. there is no guarantee that after a volatile variable is written that everything done by the thread will be visible to *all other threads*.

Comment: It is ok, but i think question is related not to only this variable but to all thread cache, which shuld be synchronize too(do not  remember from where i know this). and a question is more concrette -  does it go ahead and sync every frame? actually, i'm interesting in correct answer to.

Comment: @msangel - did you read my answer carefully?  "_everything_ done by a thread before it writes a volatile variable..."

Comment: @msangel In theory the JVM must guarantee what jtahlborn describes it - in practice all the cache is flushed. In other words, current JVMs implement volatile semantics in a way that goes beyond what the memory model requires, but they don't have to and might not do it any more in the future.

Comment: @assylias, does this operation of flushing all local thread memory is atomic(or proceeds in some critical section)? because it is not only one variable - thread can cache a lot of variables and sync these to main mamory can take some time(during which these variables can be chanhge, or not?) or this operation just happand in same thread so not need to lock this memory? also i'm interesting in this usecase - if two threads begin flushing local thread cache in same time? in describtion  above is saying, that writting only valatile variable is locking, but what about other memory?

Comment: @msangel that is mostly irrelevant from Java's perspective - there is no notion of "flushing" in the Java Memory Model. If you do want to know what really happens under the hood, you should read [this](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html). This is how the compilers implement the JMM in practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a `volatile` variable all the JVM promises is that **that variable** contains the latest value that has been written to it by any thread.

Behind the scenes the system is **probably** causing a complete cache flush of all threads to RAM before the read occurs but this is not specified and therefore may or may not happen.

So, in summary, it **could** be every frame but it **will** include the variable accessed.

Pay a visit to Brian Goetz's excellent [Java theory and practice: Managing volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/). You will find comments such as:

> ... threads will automatically see the most up-to-date value for volatile variables.

and that really sums it up, the important point here is that `volatile` variables are no more than that. They are **not a cache flushing mechanism**, although they use cache flushing to achieve their goal.

Comment: actually, this is not correct, volatile variables have the _same memory semantics as synchronization_.  this means that reading from a volatile variable guarantees that you will see every value written by the thread which last wrote the volatile variable.  that is indeed a form of cache flush.  it's possible this answer may be partially correct, but at this point it is too vague.